# mtouch returning Cannot bundle unregistered option -o when trying to use Flurry Analytics in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use Flurry analytics in an IPad app as described here:

http://blog.kevfoo.com/index.php/2010/08/monotouch-flurry-analytics-bindings/

However I keep getting this error message from mtouch:
Cannot bundle unregistered option '-o'. But I cannot see any unregistrered option -o.

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/klaus/Projects/IPadTest/IPadTest/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/IPadTest.app" "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" "-r=/Users/klaus/Projects/IPadTest/IPadTest/FlurryWithLocation.dll" -debug -nolink "-sdk=4.2" -v -v -v -gcc_flags “-v -Xlinker -L/Users/klaus/Projects/IPadTest/IPadTest -lFlurryWithLocation -framework CFNetwork -force_load /Users/klaus/Projects/IPadTest/IPadTest/libFlurryWithLocation.a” "/Users/klaus/Projects/IPadTest/IPadTest/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/IPadTest.exe"
mtouch: Cannot bundle unregistered option '-o'.

Comment: Please attach the complete build output, but your gcc flags look wrong, you never have -lFlurryWithLocation in them.

Comment: Sorry, but there is. Found out that the qoutes I copied apparently made mtouch go crazy. After removing the quoted and typing them again the problem was solved. But thank you for commenting. And for your great work with monotouch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on Kevin's blog this only works for libraries compiled with no-thumb. Flurry was kind enough to create such a library for us and allowed us to make it available publicly. You can get it here: http://eodsoft.com/blog/?p=12

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the qoutes I copied apparently made mtouch go crazy. After removing the quoted and typing them again the problem was solved